# An error when sending an email from outlook using the telnet command

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, telnet, starttls

I'm trying to send an email from my @outlook account to my gmail account.

```
SEND:    `telnet smtp.live.com 587`. I am connected. 
SEND: `   HELO blu169.mail.live.com`. 
RECEIVE: `250 BLU0-SMTP371.phx.gbl Hello [IP ADDRESS]`. 
SEND: `   MAIL FROM: myemail@outlook.com` 
RECEIVE: `530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first`
```

What kind of a STARTTLS command must I enter?

Are there other commands in the next few commands that I must enter that deviate from the basic protocols of sending an email using telnet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must authenticate yourself to use smtp.live.com:587 (SMTP `AUTH`).

smtp.live.com:587 offers only *plain text* authentications methods (`LOGIN` and `PLAIN`) in response to `EHLO` (Extended HeLO) issued after turning encryption on (`STARTTLS`). The offered authentication methods are **NOT** secure over unencrypted "open internet" SMTP connection.

So the message means: You must issue a STARTTLS command to be able to issue required AUTH command.

Comment: The command you are being instructed to issue is, simply, `STARTTLS`. However, this command initiates an attempt to encrypt the communications stream, so if you really are using telnet to perform a manual SMTP transaction, you aren't really going to be able to.

Answer (score 0):

"tools-> Account Settings" then double click the "email account" then click More Settings->Advanced tab set the encryption to "Auto"